# i want to have many users on my php user login

Tags: php

i want have a multiple user login and redirects them to a specific folder such as when i have user login of John, and when John logs in it redirects John to account_john/welcome.php, and another when i have a user called Alex and it goes to account_alex/welcome.php, is there anyone who can give me a little tips about that

here is my code:

```
    $password = md5(md5("agdagsjagsj".$password."77gggg77g7g7g"));

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $dbid = $row['id'];
        $dbuser = $row['username'];
        $dbpass = $row['password'];         
        $dbactive = $row['active'];

        if ($password == $dbpass) {
            if($dbactive == 1) {

                $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                header("Location: ./processing.php");

                }
                else
                    echo "Your account is not active you need to activate your account. $form";

            }
            else
                echo "Your Password is incorrect. $form";

    }
    else
        echo "Your Username is not listed in our database. $form";

    mysql_close();


}
else 
    echo "You enter no password. $form";


}
else

    echo "Please enter your username. $form";
```

Comment: and then I'm going to type `account_admin/welcome.php` and hack your site.

Comment: anyone can give me help on this

Comment: no, sorry, we can't help you more than how scott helme already did in his answer.

Comment: i have try so much but no solution, if anyone could help me on this i will appreciate a lot please

Comment: your question isn't answerable as it is now. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To get started, you need to stop using md5 hashing, it's woefully inadequate. The PHP help docs have a lot of info on this [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Also, the mysql interface is now deprecated. You should look at MySQLi or PDO MySQL instead. If you look at the help docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) you can see the big red warning about this.

I'd advise instead of using a specific sub-directory per user that you use a generic `welcome.php` that loads content based on the signed in user or directory management will quickly become an issue. Not to mention source management if all the files are unique also.

It doesn't seem there is much code in this regard for me to comment on. SO is intended to help you, not to provide full solutions. If you update your question to include code that you have tried so far, myself and others can provide assistance with it.

Comment: haven't try any code and thats the code i already tried

Comment: can you give me help on this